# catkin make error, dji sdk launch file error

Tags: cmake, ros, dji-sdk

I'm trying to activate my work space to control DJI M210 RTK V2, i get two errors, the first error is when i use (catkin_make) and I've attached the codes that i get, and the second error is when i launch the package (roslaunch dji_sdk sdk.launch) and also its in the attachment as you see.

```
dji@manifold2:~/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
dji@manifold2:~/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws
Source space: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/src
Build space: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/build
Devel space: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/devel
Install space: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.11
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - dji_sdk
-- ~~  - dji_sdk_demo
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'dji_sdk'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Using Finddjiosdk-core.cmake find djiosdk-core
-- Found djiosdk-core:
--  - Includes: /usr/local/include
--  - Libraries: /usr/local/lib/libdjiosdk-core.a
-- dji_sdk: 13 messages, 28 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'dji_sdk_demo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk_demo)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/devel/share/dji_sdk/cmake/dji_sdkConfig.cmake:172 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "nmea_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    nmea_msgsConfig.cmake
    nmea_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "nmea_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "nmea_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "nmea_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  Onboard-SDK-ROS/dji_sdk_demo/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install the nmea_msgs package.
Just run the command: 
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-nmea-msgs

Comment: i have done that but still i get the same error. it replayed me this message: 
Err:1404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Failed to fetch 404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

Comment: you can download the nmea_msgs package from the ros website:[link](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_msgs/tree/jade-devel) Then put the package in the /home/dji/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws/src/ and unzip it.